# How to access a specific row in a column using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm stuck while developing a dashboboard using Pandas. This is the scenario:

I'm importing and transforming a CSV file in order to get some insights about a team I am working with.

```
|ID      |Area Path                             | 
|--------|--------------------------------------|
| 544    | [Level 1, Level 2, Level 3]          |
| 545    | [Level 1, Level 2]                   |
| 546    | [Level 1]                            |
| 547    | [Level 1, Level 2, Level 3, Level 4] |
```

As you can see, the column *Area Path* does not have a pattern. Sometimes I'll find a list with 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 items on it.

I'm facing a problem in order to access each line in this column to get the information I need. If the list has only one item, I must use the [0] position, if the list has 2 or more items, I must use the [1] position.

I've tried to do different things and this one below is my last attempt:

```
def Extract(lst):
    if dados['Area Path'].str.len() == 1:
      return [item[0] for item in dados['Area Path']]
    elif dados['Area Path'].str.len() == 2:
      return [item[-1] for item in dados['Area Path']]
    elif dados['Area Path'].str.len() == 3:
      return [item[1] for item in dados['Area Path']]
    elif dados['Area Path'].str.len() == 4:
      return [item[1] for item in dados['Area Path']]

lst = [dados['Area Path']]
indice_novo = Extract(lst)
dados['Team'] = indice_novo
```

The problem is that I'm not able to iterate over the list that is the column. The output provided by `.str.len()` is great, but it does not help me completely.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks,
Marcelo

Comment: Is Area Path a true list or is it a string variable?

Comment: Actually, it's a list, but I've created it. The original format is: `Level 1\Level 2\Level 3\Level 4`.

In order to transform it into a list, I've used `dados['Area Path'] = dados['Area Path'].str.split('\\')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `map()`

```
df['Area Path'].map(lambda x: x[0] if len(x) == 1 else x[1])
```

or

```
df['Area Path'].str[:2].str[-1]
```

Output:

```
0    Level 2
1    Level 2
2    Level 1
3    Level 2
Name: Area Path, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, the `Area Path` column contains lists. If so, you are accessing the columns incorrectly. The correct way to access the lists in the columns would be:

```
lst = dados['Area Path'].tolist()
```

This will populate the `lst` variable with a list of lists, which looks something like:

```
[['Level 1', 'Level 2', 'Level 3'], ['Level 1', 'Level 2'], ['Level 1'], ...]
```

Then, in your Extract() function, you can perform your filtering based on the required logic:

```
def Extract(list_of_lists):
    new_list = []
    for lst in list_of_lists:
        # Will fail if 'Area Path' contains None, NaN values
        if len(lst) == 1:
            new_list.append(lst[0])
        else:
            new_list.append(lst[1])
    return new_list

indice_novo = Extract(lst)
dados['Team'] = indice_novo
```

This answer is based on your code and may not be the most optimized way to do this.